A sharp version of a Tauberian theorem
The following Tauberian theorem is true (see Theorem I.11.1 of ''Tauberian theory: A century of developments''). Let $ a_n $ a sequence of real numbers.
If $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n $ converges for $|x|<1$ and the limit $ \lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)f(x) = \ell$ exists and is finite, then under the Tauberian condition $-C \leq a_n \leq C$ we have that $$ \sigma_n:=\frac{a_1+\dots a_n}{n} \to \ell. $$
Question Is it true that under the same Tauberian condition, if
\begin{align*}
a= \liminf_{x\to 1}(1-x)f(x) & \quad b= \limsup_{x\to 1}(1-x) f(x) \\ 
\alpha = \liminf \sigma_n & \quad \beta = \limsup_n \sigma_n
\end{align*}  Does necessarily then $$ a \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq b ? $$
EDIT:

Karamata's original proof seems to break down.
The closest result I could find in the literature is a stream of research which generally goes under the name "Tauberian constans" (see for example Maddox, Tauberian Constants) which seem to suggest that under these hypothesis $|\alpha - a| \leq \tau \sup|a_n|$, with $\tau$ an absolute constant, but still this is not entirely clear to me.


Did you try to mimic the Karamata's proof presented in the book which you cite?

Well, seriously no, but essentially Karamata considers the linear space of functions g such that $\lim_{x\to 1}(1−x)\sum a_ng(x^n)=\int_0^1g(t)dt$, I do not immediately see a good substitute for this idea.

Consider not equality, but a lower bound. This is a cone, not a linear space, but proceed fingers crossed

@FedorPetrov, Sure, but the problem is that if it is only a cone then showing that the monomials are inside it, it doesn't allow you to pass to all polynomials.

Please use a high-level tag like "ca.classical-analysis-and-odes". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

@GHfromMO Thanks, good to know !
